# Unity - display Json array from server

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm making a quiz game and I'm stuck at this problem that is probably easy to do.
I have this script, which gets JSON data from server and separates it:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System;
using TMPro;

[Serializable]
public class RootObject
{
    public Results[] Result;
}

[Serializable]
public class Results
{
    public string id;
    public string question;
    public string answer1;
    public string answer2;
    public string answer3;
    public string answer4c;
}

public class DataLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PickPlace pickplace;
    public string URLBase;

    public void GetQustion()
    {
        URLBase = pickplace.url;
        StartCoroutine(Run());
    }

    IEnumerator Run()
    {
        var req = CreateReturnPlayerDataRequest();
        yield return req.SendWebRequest();
        var results = HandleReturnPlayerDataRequest(req);
        // Izvada konsolē saņemtos datus
        Debug.Log("Quesiton: " + results.Result[0].question + " Answer1: " + results.Result[0].answer1 + " Answer2: " + results.Result[0].answer2 + " Answer3: " + results.Result[0].answer3 + " Answer4: " + results.Result[0].answer4c);

    }

    public UnityWebRequest CreateReturnPlayerDataRequest()
    {
        var req = UnityWebRequest.Get(URLBase);
        return req;
    }

    public static RootObject HandleReturnPlayerDataRequest(UnityWebRequest req)
    {
        if (req.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to POST /player/register");
            return new RootObject();
        }
        var results = JsonUtility.FromJson<RootObject>("{\"Result\":" + req.downloadHandler.text + "}");
        return results;
    }

}
```

My question is:
How can I call out array in, for example my `GameManager` script and call out separated data, so that I can put for example question text from JSON data into Text object and all 4 answers to buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you have a method to start the request but you never **wait until / will know** when it is done!

I would simply use an `Action<RootObject>` as parameter so you can add a callback listener and react to the result when it is invoked.

```
public class DataLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PickPlace pickplace;
    public string URLBase;

    public void GetQuestions(Action<RootObject> onSuccess)
    {
        URLBase = pickplace.url;

        StartCoroutine(Run(onSuccess));
    }

    IEnumerator Run(Action<RootObject> onSuccess)
    {
        var req = CreateReturnPlayerDataRequest();

        yield return req.SendWebRequest();

        var results = HandleReturnPlayerDataRequest(req);

        if(results == null)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        Debug.Log("Quesiton: " + results.Result[0].question + " Answer1: " + results.Result[0].answer1 + " Answer2: " + results.Result[0].answer2 + " Answer3: " + results.Result[0].answer3 + " Answer4: " + results.Result[0].answer4c);

        // Now invoke the Callback so whoever started the post call gets the results
        onSuccess?.Invoke(results);
    }

    public UnityWebRequest CreateReturnPlayerDataRequest()
    {
        var req = UnityWebRequest.Get(URLBase);
        return req;
    }

    private RootObject HandleReturnPlayerDataRequest(UnityWebRequest req)
    {
        if(req.isHttpError || req.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Failed to POST /player/register! Failed with {req.responseCode} - Reason: {req.error}");
            onDone?.Invoke(null);
            return null;
        }

        var results = JsonUtility.FromJson<RootObject>("{\"Result\":" + req.downloadHandler.text + "}");
        return results;
    }
}
```

So now you can call it from another class like e.g.

```
// Drag these in via the Inspector
[SerializeField] private DataLoader dataLoader;
[Space]
[SerializeField] private Text questionText;
[Space]
[SerializeField] private Text button1Text;
[SerializeField] private Text button2Text;
[SerializeField] private Text button3Text;
[SerializeField] private Text button3Text;

public void SomeMethod()
{
    // Do the post call and react once the results are there either as lambda expression
    dataLoader.GetQuestions(results => {
        Debug.Log("Successfully received data. Will update GUI", this);

        // do something with the results now e.g.
        var first = results.Result[0];

        questionText.text = first.question;
        button1Text.text = first.answer1;
        button2Text.text = first.answer2;
        button3Text.text = first.answer3;
        button4Text.text = first.answer4;
    });

    // alternatively you can do the same also using a method
    dataLoader.GetQuestions(OnPostRequestFinished);
} 

private void OnPostRequestFinished(RootObject results)
{
    Debug.Log("Successfully received data. Will update GUI", this);

    // do something with the results now e.g.
    var first = results.Result[0];

    questionText.text = first.question;
    button1Text.text = first.answer1;
    button2Text.text = first.answer2;
    button3Text.text = first.answer3;
    button4Text.text = first.answer4;
}
```

Comment: After puting  `IEnumerator Run(Action<Results> onSuccess)` I cant start Coroutine `StartCoroutine(Run(onSuccess));` it shows: cannot convert from System.Action<RootObject> to System.Action<Results>

Comment: Im trying `private void OnPostRequestFinished(RootObject results)` metod from your example, but it doesnt get the data and in gameobject shows nothing, just empty object without any text.

Comment: And in GameManager arrays there is no data.

Comment: its a typo: it should be `Action<RootObject>` instead of `Action<Result>`